# Excel VBA - Loop VBAs with Data from Subfolder

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main Excel file and CSV data in several subfolders. I want now to load the CSVs from one subfolder, start another VBA-Script and then go to the next subfolder.

Example:

- MyExcelFile.xlsm
- Country 1
- ../Data1.csv
- ../Data2.csv
- Country 2
- ../Data3.csv
- ../Data4.csv

Country1    Report1.csv     Report2.csv Country2
    Report3.csv     Report4.csv

Load all CSVs from Country1, generate a Report, then go to Country2 and generate the report with this data.

Here is my VBA to load the CSVs (thanks to the Author mentioned):

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire
'Date:      8/16/2010
'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets
Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = (Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\")                  'path to     CSV files, include the final \
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'no error messages, take default answers
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.txt")         'start the CSV file listing

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV, xlDelimited, Delimiter:=",", Format:=6, Local:=False)                  'open a CSV file
        wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete                       'delete sheet if it exists
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)    'move new sheet into Mstr
        Columns.AutoFit             'clean up display
        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain me, how I can go to all Subfolders and hand over the "Subfolder-Name" the the ImportCSVs-CSV? I was looking for this the whole afternoon, but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you so much in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating objects is the concept here. My way is loop through all CSV files in the target folder(includes its subfolders) , and then import those CSV meet my criteria into a new temp folder. 
Then you can use your current code to load all CSV to mastersheet, rename and control the temp folder whatever. Hope this helps.

```
Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object, tempFolder As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object
Dim ToPath As String

ToPath = "V:\MasterFolder\"
FromPath = "V:\TargetFolder\"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

'clean Masterfolder first
Set tempFolder = Fso.GetFolder(ToPath)
For Each File In tempFolder.Files
    File.Delete
Next File

'loop through each subfolders
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files
        If FileInFolder.Name Like "*DATA*" Then 'criteria
            FileInFolder.Copy ToPath
        End If
    Next FileInFolder
Next objSubFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your help. I managed to do exactly what i wanted with the following code:

```
Sub RunAll()

Dim Fso As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object, tempFolder 
As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim fpath As String
Dim FileInFolder As Object
Dim ToPath As String
Dim temporaryFolder As String

temporaryFolder = "Temp"
fpath = (Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\")
FromPath = fpath
ToPath = fpath & temporaryFolder & "\"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

Set objFolder = Fso.GetFolder(FromPath)

'clean Masterfolder first
Set tempFolder = Fso.GetFolder(ToPath)

'loop through each subfolders
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    For Each File In tempFolder.Files
        File.Delete
    Next File

    For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files
        If FileInFolder.Name Like "*REPORT*.txt" Then 'criteria
            FileInFolder.Copy ToPath
        End If
    Next FileInFolder

    'Check if folder is empty
    If Dir(ToPath & "*.*") = "" Then

    Else
        Call ImportCSVs
        Call ImportData
        Call PrintPDF
    End If


Next objSubFolder

Call CloseFile

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should mark @NoAppleOnHead's reply as the answer, instead of your own answer, to be fair.

Comment: Sure, changed it :-)